# Fill every combination of three ranges in ascending order with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have three ranges, and I would like to fill every combination in ascending order with Excel. The ranges are:

1. Power: 2-30 (increment by 1)
2. ON Time: 100-10000 (increment by 100)
3. OFF time: 100-10000 (increment by 100)

This should give me 29 × 100 × 100 = 290,000 rows with 3 columns.

The output should look like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Power (W) | On Time (ms) | Off Time (ms) |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | 100          | 100           |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | 100          | 200           |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | 100          | 300           |
--------------------------------------------
| 2         | 100          | 400           |
--------------------------------------------
etc..
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the first row as follows:

- `A1` : `=INT((ROW()-2)/10000)+2`
- `B1` : `=(MOD(INT((ROW()-2)/100),100)+1)*100`
- `C1` : `=(MOD((ROW()-2),100)+1)*100`

and drag/fill down the desired number of rows. 
If you have an actual heading row, change all occurrences of `ROW()-1` to `ROW()-2`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. For others, hit `F5` to go to a row, then use `CTRL+SHIFT+UP` to select all rows between, then `CTRL+D` to fill down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA solution. Tested and working in Office 2013

```
Sub FillCombinations()
For intPower = 2 To 30
    For intOn = 100 To 10000 Step 100
        For intOff = 100 To 10000 Step 100
            intRow = intRow + 1
            Cells(intRow, 1) = intPower
            Cells(intRow, 2) = intOn
            Cells(intRow, 3) = intOff
        Next intOff
    Next intOn
Next intPower
End Sub
```

If you don't know how to use VBA:

1. Open Excel and press **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** to open the VBA editor
2. Paste the macro above and run it with **<kbd>F5</kbd>**

It will fill down all possible combinations in column A,B and C in your active sheet.
Btw. they are 290.000 rows starting at row 1 :)

Comment: Thanks Nixda, though I chose Scott's answer since he didn't use VBA :D